# Добавление множества CardView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть задача организовать приложение с использованием виджета `CardView`, но проблема в том, что точное количество элементов неизвестно. Данные берутся из *БД*, и элементы должны добавляться автоматически.

Хочу совет по реализации. Конечно, нет смысла делать все в разметке, но вот добавление в классе ещё не освоил.

Comment: Множество `CardView` - это скорее всего список. `ListView` (`RecyclerView`)  - это адаптер. Адаптер - это данные из БД. Все должно решится само-собой: добавляются данные - обновляется список - появляются карточки.

Comment: @pavlofff это понятно, получается нужно кастомизировать listview?

Comment: Дописал в первом комментарии. Так же кастомизируешь айтемы, пишешь свой адаптер , при добавлении данных в БД делаешь адаптеру `notifyDataSetChanged()`и готово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Гайдлайн от гугла по RecyclerView с CardView.](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/material/lists-cards.html)
Это должно помочь, там пример с объяснением.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!

Answer (score 2):

Я знаю три способа:

1. Рекомендуемый - [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)
2. Немного устаревший, но не depricated - [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)
3. Для любителей сделать посвоему - [ViewGroup.addView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29)

Comment: Для меня сложность была в том, что на тот момент было обязательно делать свой RecyclerView.Adapter. Но сейчас этой проблемы уже нет. Обновил ответ

Comment: адаптеры в андроиде достаточно гибкая, удобная и простая вещь, если для вас они составляю сложность, то скорее всего вы просто не понимаете как они работают, рекомендую углубиться и все же разобраться, тогда страх перед кастомными адаптерами пройдет и откроется множество возможностей.